# How to execute ant scripts in a differing directory to a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, subshell, ant

I'm writing a shell script to automate an elaborate build process. It includes execution of multiple `ant` scripts located in different directories.

The shell script is in my home directory, while the ant scripts are located in:
`/opt/myApp/module1/ ant -f patch.xml`, and `/opt/myApp2/module2 ant build.xml`.

How can I invoke ant command in my shell script, from a different folder location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a module in master ant file which contains corresponding ant files.
For eg:

You can make a master file as

> /opt/Makefile

```
all:
(make module1)
(make module2)

module1:
(cd myApp/module1/; ant -f patch.xml)

module2:
(cd myApp2/module2; ant -buildfile build.xml)
```

Then you can run the master Makefile as:

> `$ make Makefile all`

Answer (score 0):

Just as `VAR=/opt/myapp` and then using `$VAR` to substitute the value. Like `$VAR/module1/ant -f patch.xml`

Comment: Which shell uses the syntax $(VAR) ?

Comment: My bad. Sorry. Remove the parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that's not what I'm asking for. I need to **invoke the ant execution from my shell script**